# what happens when we specify column name in split function in R?

Tags: r, split-function

What is the difference between these two lines of codes in R?

```
split = sample.split(dataset$Customer_Segment, SplitRatio = 0.8)

split = sample.split(dataset, SplitRatio = 0.8)
```

Comment: From which package is `sample.split` function from? Did you look at it's documentation at `?sample.split` it should have more information about this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you mean `caTools::sample.split`, function is based on `length` value of object.

let's assume dataset has 100 rows and 10 columns

`length(dataset$Customer_Segment)` is 100 (equal to `nrow(dataset)`), so function return vector 80 TRUE and 20 FALSE value

since `length(dataset)` is 10 (equal to `ncol(dataset)`) so function return vector 8 TRUE and 2 FALSE

Comment: Thanks for your response, however I cannot up vote it since I have not enough reputation.